# Автоматическая вставка критического css

Tags: gulp, плагин, sass

Каким способом возможно, используя **Gulp**, вставить из SASS-файла код прямо в HTML?
К примеру, есть файл **critical.scss**, туда мы импортируем всякие normaliz'ы, reset'ы, grid'ы (типа bootstrap, foundation etc.) ну и стили до "сгиба". Нужен таск, чтобы содержимое этого файла (после компиляции, конечно), попадало прямиком в **head** нужного html-документа. Есть у кого соображения по этому поводу?